# How to delete from a Max-Heap?

Tags: heap, binary-search-tree

If we put 15 in the root, what would be the process of heapify?

```
            85
            /\
           /  \
          /    \
        55      70
        /\      /\
       /  \    /  \
      22  33  30  65
     /\   /
   14 15 15
```

What should be the way to delete 85 from the Heap?

Comment: http://www.tech-faq.com/deleting-an-element-from-a-heap.html

Comment: @Femaref: Why not? 15 is lower than 33, so the heap-property is met.

Comment: OK. My question was not at that point. I modified the heap. Just try to delete 85 and tell me what happens.

Comment: Hm, you are right. I added the binary tree property into it as well.

Comment: The heap is ok. The heap propery is that each parent is bigger then its sons. This is not a binary tree.

Comment: I wonder who upvoted "that tree isn't a heap"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are always swapping it with the larger of the two (heap property means that the parent is always larger than its children):

```
            15
            /\
           /  \
          /    \
        55      70
        /\      /\
       /  \    /  \
      22  33  30  65
     /\   
   14 15

            70
            /\
           /  \
          /    \
        55      15
        /\      /\
       /  \    /  \
      22  33  30  65
     /\   
   14 15

            70
            /\
           /  \
          /    \
        55      65
        /\      /\
       /  \    /  \
      22  33  30  15
     /\   
   14 15
```

Answer (score 1):

If you delete 85 and replace it with 15, you turn the semi-heap back into a heap by downheaping, i.e. the 15 at the root will "sink" along the path of larger children. In this case it will swap with 70 then with 65.

Edit: because we are always swapping with the larger child, it ensures we end up with a valid heap (e.g. if we swapped our 15 with 55 instead of 70, we would have 70 as a child of 55 which is no good)

Answer (score 0):

To add you put the new value as last (right to 20 in your example), and then you try to fix the heap, that is compare it with his parent, if it is larger the swap and compare again until no swap is needed (or you get to root)

In order to delete you remove you replace the last object (15 in you example) and fix the heap downward.

Comment: When I put 15 at the root and heapify, 55 should go to the root. But then what? 70 is still a candidate for getting the root. Then should we heapify the right subtree also?

Comment: No, the larger of the two gets swapped. So the 70 will be the new root.

Comment: No. 55 should not go up because this means that the parent is not bigger then its sons which is the property of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

To delete 85 which is root here.

1. You can replace with the last leaf (**15**).
2. Heapify Again [link to build heap](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms_heapify_method.htm)